Common Lebesgue integral vs upper and lower Lebesgue integral
Given a measure space $(X,{\cal A},\mu)$ there is the following definition of the Lebesgue integral:
First one defines the integral for a simple function $g=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \chi_{A_i}$, $A_i\in {\cal A}$ disjoint, $\lambda_i\geq 0$, by $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \mu(A_i)$.
Then one defines the integral of nonnegative measurable function $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ by
\begin{align*}
\int fd\mu=\sup\bigg\{\int gd\mu \mid0\leq g\leq f, g \text{ simple }\bigg\}\in [0,\infty]
\end{align*}
and for an arbitrary measurable function one defines the integral $\int fd\mu$ via $\int f^+ d\mu-\int f^- d\mu$, provided that one of them is finite (in this case the function is called quasi-integrable (maybe quasi is only the german word)).
As far as I know, this is the most common definition of Lebesgue integral. However, while reading "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions" by Evans and Gariepy I came across another definition and I want to know if these definitions are actually the same.
They define a simple function as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i \chi_{A_i}$, $A_i\in {\cal A}$ disjoint, $\lambda_i\in [-\infty,\infty]$ (So the image is now countable).
They define the Lebesgue integral of a nonnegative simple function ($\lambda_i\geq 0$) by $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i \mu(A_i)$ and say that a simple function $g$ is integrable if either $\int g^+d\mu$ or $\int g^-d\mu$ is finite and in this case they define the integral of $g$ to be
$\int g^+ d\mu-\int g^- d\mu$.
Then, for an arbitrary measurable function $f:X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ they define the upper integral
\begin{align*}
\int^* fd\mu:=\inf \bigg \{ \int gd\mu\mid g \text{ integrable, simple}, g\geq f \text{ a.e.}\bigg\}
\end{align*}
and the lower integral
\begin{align*}
\int_* fd\mu:=\sup \bigg \{ \int gd\mu\mid g \text{ integrable, simple}, g\leq f \text{ a.e.}\bigg\}.
\end{align*}
$f$ is integrable if both values coincide and this value is then the integral of $f$.
My question is the following: If we have a measurable and quasi-integrable function $f:X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ in the sense of the first definition, is the function integrable in the sense of the definition from Evans and do the integrals coincide?
And of course I also want to know if a integrable function (in the sense of Evans) is quasi-integrable in the sense of the first definition.
Remark: Evans says that for each nonnegative measurable function the upper and lower integral are the same and hence each nonnegative measurable function is integrable. I also don't immediately see why this is the case but this sounds like at least for nonnegative functions the definitions are equivalent.
I am thankful for any ideas!

I think it's the same. And I hope that the following arguments are correct. Throughout the arguments I use the fact that any simple function (from the first or second definition) is integrable w.r.t both definitions and the integrals coincide. This is easy to show.

Let’s first assume that for any non-negative function it is the same definition.

Then choose any measurable function $f:X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ and write it as $f=f^+-f^-$. If $f$ is now quasi-integrable as in your first definition it is easy to check with the definition using simple functions for $f^+,f^-$ that $f$ is integrable as in your second definition and that the integrals coincide.
If $f$ is not quasi-integrable then $\int f^+d\mu= \int f^- d\mu=\infty$. If $g$ is a simple function as in your second definition and $g\geq f$ almost everywhere then $g^+\geq f^+$ almost everywhere and hence $\int g^+ d\mu=\infty$. But the same argument gives that $\int g^- d\mu=\infty$ and hence $g$ cannot be integrable. So both the sets in the definition for the upper and lower integral are empty and therefore $f$ is not integrable as in your second definition.

We only need to consider the case of a non-negative and measurable function $f$.

Now let us assume that $f$ is not quasi-integrable as in your first definition. Recall that by the standard monotone convergence theorem the integral of your first definition equals the lower integral of the second one. Hence also the lower integral is infinite and then, of course, also the upper integral.
The hardest part is the second case when $f$ is quasi-integrable.
Here I need some approximations.
It is well-known that $f$ can be approximated by non-negative simple functions $g_n$ (as in your first definition) from below, i.e. $g_n\leq g_{n+1}\leq f, g_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f(x)$ for all $x$. Using the second definition of a simple function it is also possible to approximate $f$ from above:
For $m\in \mathbb{N}$ let $A_{n,k}:=\{x\mid f(x)\in (n-\frac{k+1}{2^m},n-\frac{k}{2^m}]\}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k=0,…,2^m-1$. Let $h_m(x)=\infty$ if $f(x)=\infty$ and $h_m(x)= n-\frac{k}{2^m}$ for $x \in A_{k,n}$. Then $h_m$ is a simple function as in your second definition and $h_m\geq f$, $h_{m+1}\leq h_m$ and $h_m-f\leq 1/2^m$. Hence $h_m$ converges to $f$.
A similar construction provides us with a non-negative simple function $g\leq f$ (as in your second definition) satisfying $g(x)\geq 1/2 f(x)$ for all $x$.
Now, let us assume that $f$ is quasi-integrable and hence, the lower integral is finite. Then, using the simple function $g$ we immediately get that also the upper integral has to be finite.
We only need to show that the upper and lower integral coincide.
We consider the sequences $g_n$ and $h_n$ (Above I wrote $h_m$ but I want to call the parameter $n$). By considering $\tilde h_n=\min\{h_n, h\}$ for any integrable simple function $h\geq f$ we can assume that $h_n$ is integrable. Now $h_n-g_n$ is bounded above by the integrable function $h_1-g_1$ and converges to $0$. Hence, the difference of the integrals also converges to $0$ by the standard dominated convergence theorem. Hence, the upper and the lower integral is the same.

Maybe I am wrong...but if $X=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$, then this function is Lebesgue-integrable in the usual sense with the value $∫_X f= 1$.
But I would say with the second definition we get $∫^* f = ∞$. Because  $f$ is unbounded around $x=0$ and so all extended simple functions must have the value $∞$ on a small set in $X$ around $x=0$. So every integral of an extended simple function $g≥f$ must have an infinite value and so the infimum of all that values. Maybe someone corrects me if I am misthinking here...
